# Load/Store unit and in pipeline

Tags: arm, cpu-architecture, cpu-cache, cortex-a8

I am learning about CPU and pipeline.  We know In processors pipeline execute stage exist some load store units.

Now I want to know that if we have a load instruction that take a long time because requested data did not exist in cache, next load instruction won't execute until first load resolved in out of order cpu unless we have another load/store unit in pipeline execute stage?

What is the corresponding behavior of an in-order CPU?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Will a cache-miss load block later loads?  CPUs can be designed to avoid it.**

The terms you're looking for are **hit under miss** for cache accesses while waiting for an outstanding cache miss, and **miss under miss** for having multiple cache misses outstanding (memory level parallelism).

See https://www.ece.ucsb.edu/~strukov/ece154BSpring2018/week3.pdf for Nonblocking cache and pipelined cache.

---

In an **out-of-order CPU** this can be handled by having the load instruction give temporarily, and replay again later from the scheduler.  That's what Intel x86 CPUs do, at least.  CPUs with a weakly-ordered memory model like ARM might only need to have a load buffer wait for that cache line to arrive at L1d cache without having to rerun the load instruction.

**On an in-order pipeline**, loads can be [scoreboarded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scoreboarding) so nothing stalls until you try to actually read a register that was written by a cache-miss load.  You need some load buffers to wait for incoming cache lines, but then hit-under-miss and miss-under-miss just work.

(Paul Clayton posted an answer with slightly more detail on https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/98551/what-happens-on-a-cache-miss)

Remember that in-order only means instructions have to *start* executing in program order.  High-latency instructions like division, or especially stores and loads, can complete out of order.  Even cache *hit* stores have enough latency on a modern high-speed in-order design that you want to let other instructions run in the shadow of that latency.

---

Different complexity levels of pipelines might or might not support hit-under-miss and/or miss-under-miss.  i.e. different amounts of MLP (Memory Level Parallelism).

Out-of-order CPUs almost always support both; one of the *major* benefits of OoO exec is hiding memory latency, as well as ALU latency.

---

[Cortex-A8's glossary](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0344k/Cbaifdib.html) mentions Hit Under Miss, but IDK where they actually use the term to specifically say that A8 supports it or not.

I did find [16.4.2. Memory system effects on instruction timings](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ddi0344k/ch16s04s02.html) which says:

> Because the processor is a statically scheduled design, any stall from the memory system can result in the minimum of a 8-cycle delay. This 8-cycle delay minimum is balanced with the minimum number of possible cycles to receive data from the L2 cache in the case of an L1 load miss. Table 16.16 gives the most common cases that **can result in an instruction replay because of a memory system stall**.

The list of conditions includes an L1 Load data miss.  And a subsequent L2 miss can result in another replay, delaying later instructions for another 8 cycles.

This really sounds like A8 does *not* support anything under a cache miss, and instead basically stalls.

Comment: The cortex-A8 also has `PLD` or preload which does a cache load of an address;  It does nothing if the address is L1 or L2 hit or a TLB miss (needs to page walk to see if it is cacheable).  So if you have somewhat ordered access, you can use `PLD` to ensure the data is available in the cache and avoid stalls.

Comment: @artlessnoise: Is that generally necessary on A8 to achieve any MLP, or is there a HW prefetcher for simple sequential-access patterns?

Comment: It is all software driven.  The compiler is expected to insert the `PLD` as it knows the access pattern.  Generally it is only the L2 size that needs to get filled.  Normally a transfer from L2 to L1 is not so bad and adding many `PLD` to get the L1 filled will pollute the instruction stream.  The cortex-A8 was one of the first ARMv7a CPUs.  It is unlikely to have any MLP features.  If things are plugged into a wall, you can burn power like crazy.  ARMs try not to do this.  Gcc doesn't even emit `PLD` for the cortex-A8, but will for the cortex-a9; the programmer can manually insert them.